# Filtering multiple null values from Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm still working on learning powershell. I need to pull email and manager email from AD accounts in a group but exclude any records that have manager blank or email blank. I don't think I can 'where' for two where conditions, so I can get one or the other.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "groupname" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -properties * | where manager -NE $null | select displayname, EmailAddress, @{Name="ManagerEmail";Expression={(Get-ADUser -property Emailaddress $_.manager).emailaddress}} | export-csv -path c:\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

How would I go about getting both filtered out?

Comment: I commend to your attention [Get-Help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](http://powershellhelp.space/about/about_activedirectory_filter-psv5.php). It appears that you can, in fact, combine expressions for filtering on multiple attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use and should use the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) or [LDAP Filter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) for this instead of doing the filtering with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```bash
$group = (Get-ADGroup groupname).DistinguishedName
$managerMap = @{}
$params = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$group)(mail=*)(manager=*))"
    Properties = 'mail', 'manager'
}

Get-ADUser @params | ForEach-Object {
    if(-not $managerMap.ContainsKey($_.manager)) {
        $managerMap[$_.manager] = (Get-ADUser $_.manager -Properties mail).mail
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        DisplayName  = $_.DisplayName
        EmailAddress = $_.mail
        ManagerEmail = $managerMap[$_.manager]
    }
} | Export-Csv 'c:\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Details of the LDAP Filter:

```bash
(& # AND, all conditions must be met
    (memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$group) # user is a member of `$group` (recursively)
    (mail=*) # mail attribute is not null
    (manager=*) # manager attribute is not null
) # closing AND
```

Comment: The `-Filter` of `Get-ADUser` doesn't have to be LDAP syntax; according to the Get-Help output I linked to above (and which also appears to be in the link you gave), he can use (if I'm translating the LDAP correctly) `-Filter "Mail -like '*' -and Manager -like '*'"`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin added link to LDAP Filter